# How to work with data structures in Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I'm trying to write a simple Terminal game in Haskell

I have a function:

```
moveDirection :: Direction -> Position -> Position
```

which is supposed to move a player. A player looks like this:

```
data Player = Player String Position Hp
```

So I want to apply the `moveDirection` function to `Player`. I could easily do this writing a *lift* function (I don't know how to call this type of function otherwise):

```
movePlayer :: (Position -> Position) -> Player -> Player
```

But I already see myself doing this quite a lot of times, every time I want to act on some part of a data structure.
Is there some easier way to do this? Some common idioms?